# How can i set readonly property in razor?

Tags: razor

```
@if (Model.Amount!=null)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>Amount</td>
           <td><b>:</b></td>
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { readonly= true})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
           </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make it readonly why not use a Label instead ?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Amount)
```

Just read your comment on the other answer

> I need to make readonly to true when amount is not null and readonly
>   to false when amount is null

A simple if else should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

`EditorFor` as no overload with takes `htmlAttributes` as parameters...

You could simply do an if else

```
@if (Model.Amount != null) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount)
}
else {
   //or @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Amount)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new{@readonly = "readonly"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new {  @readonly = "readonly"})
```

Comment: I need to make readonly to true when amount is not null and readonly to false when amount is null